# Selecting one row per unique JSONB value in Postgres

Tags: node.js, json, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to get the newest version of data from each unique `"data"->>'account'` but only for a specific parent UUID. I want to be able to keep historical data as well, so updating the rows is not an option.

The data looks like this:

```
| id     | name       | parent | data                            | updated | created |
|--------|------------|--------|---------------------------------|---------|---------|
| uuid-a | First      | uuid-x | {"account": 1001, "value": 700} | date    | date    |
| uuid-b | Irrelevant | uuid-y | {"account": 9999, "value": 300} | date    | date    |
| uuid-c | Second     | uuid-x | {"account": 1002, "value": 500} | date    | date    |
| uuid-d | Third      | uuid-x | {"account": 1003, "value": 200} | date    | date    |
| uuid-e | Old        | uuid-x | {"account": 1003, "value": 100} | date    | date    |
...
```

I have tried using `DISTINCT ON` and `GROUP BY` to only get one row per unique `"data"->>'account'`, but I have not been able to write a query that works. My most recent query attempt looks something like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("data"->>'account') * -- Select only one row per unique 'account'
FROM "table"                              -- Define the source table
WHERE "parent" = 'uuid-x'                 -- Get only rows for the correct parent
ORDER BY "created" DESC                   -- Get the newest data
```

The output I want from the query with the above data as an example is:

```
| id     | name   | parent | data                            | updated | created |
|--------|--------|--------|---------------------------------|---------|---------|
| uuid-a | First  | uuid-x | {"account": 1001, "value": 700} | date    | date    |
| uuid-c | Second | uuid-x | {"account": 1002, "value": 500} | date    | date    |
| uuid-d | Third  | uuid-x | {"account": 1003, "value": 200} | date    | date    |
```

Currently I am faced with an error about ordering by `"created"` not being possible:

`SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions`

I have tried to figure out why I receive this error - and how to fix it as well, but I have not been able to solve it using other resources. I am attempting to perform these actions from a NodeJS/SequelizeJS environment, but that should not matter for this specific question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It wants you to use `ORDER BY "data"->>'account' ASC, "created" DESC`

Comment: Indeed when you use `DISTINCT ON`, you must always sort first by the column on which you apply it. "The `DISTINCT ON` expression(s) must match the leftmost `ORDER BY` expression(s)." https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT